React Component Not Rendering Data from API Call
I'm working on a React project and I'm having trouble displaying data fetched from an API in my Movies component. The data is correctly logged in the console, but it doesn't show up on the page. I need some help figuring out why.
Here's the code for my API call:
import axios from 'axios';

const BASE_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000';

export const getMovie = async (mood) => {
    try {
        console.log('Fetching movies for mood:', mood);
        const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/recomendar`, {
            params: { mood },
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
            }
        });
        console.log(response.data);
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching movies:', error);
        throw error;
    }
};

And here's the Movies component where I'm trying to display the data in HTML:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getMovie } from "../services/api";

const Movies = ({ mood }) => {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMovies = async () => {
      if (mood) {
        try {
          const moviesData = await getMovie(mood);
          console.log(moviesData);  // This logs the data correctly
          setMovies(moviesData);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error fetching movies:", error);
        }
      }
    };

    fetchMovies();
  }, [mood]);

  return (
    <div style={{ padding: "128px" }}>
      <h3>Movies</h3>
      <ul>
        {movies.map((movie) => (
          <li key={movie.id}>
            <div>{movie.title}</div>
            <div>{movie.genre}</div>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Movies;


How the data is coming:

In the Html, the ul tag is empty

I am getting the mood from the user selection through the Onclick in the Main component
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import Section from "./Section";
import Button from "./Button";
import curve from "../assets/curve.png";
import { moods } from "../constants/mood";
import { getMovie } from "../services/api";
import { useState } from "react";

export const Main = () => {


  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

  const handleMoodSelect = async (mood) => {
    try {
      const moviesData = await getMovie(mood);
      setMovies(moviesData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching movies:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Section className="pt-[12rem] -mt-[5.25rem] mb-8" customPaddings id="main">
      <div className="container relative">
        <div className="relative z-1 max-w-[62rem] mx-auto text-center mb-[3.875rem] md:mb-20 lg:mb-[6.25rem]">
          <h1 className="h1 mb-6">
            Descubra filmes incríveis com base no seu{" "}
            <span className="inline-block relative h1">
              humor
              <img
                src={curve}
                className="absolute top-full left-0 w-full xl:-mt-2"
                width={624}
                height={28}
                alt="Curva"
              />
            </span>
          </h1>
          <span className="inline-block relative h1">
            <img
              src={curve}
              className="absolute top-full left-0 w-full xl:-mt-2"
              width={624}
              height={28}
              alt="Curva"
            />
          </span>
          <p className="body-1 max-w-3xl mx-auto mb-6 text-n-2 lg:mb-8">
            A pergunta é: Como você está se sentindo hoje?
          </p>
          <Button white>Começar agora</Button>
        </div>

        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-x-4 gap-y-4">
          {moods.map((mood) => (
            <button onClick={() => handleMoodSelect(mood.title)}>
            <Link to={`/movies/${mood.title}`}>
              <div className="mb-2 p-4 rounded-lg relative">
                <div
                  className="absolute inset-0 cursor-pointer"
                  style={{
                    borderRadius: "5px",
                    padding: "2px",
                    background:
                      "linear-gradient(225deg, #FFC876, #79FFF7, #9F53FF, #FF98E2, #FFC876)",
                    WebkitMask:
                      "linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, linear-gradient(#fff 0 0)",
                    WebkitMaskComposite: "xor",
                    maskComposite: "exclude",
                    position: "absolute",
                    content: '""',
                    inset: 0,
                  }}
                />
                {mood.title} {mood.emoji}
              </div>
            </Link>
          </button>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Section>
  );
};



We can’t see the data that’s returned, so there’s no way to do anything other than guess. Is the data what your code thinks it is?

How does the data look like? Code seems to be correct.

@shindeshubhamm I updated the code to you see how the data looks like

@olamundo97 any chance that your issue is css? have you checked dev tools elements to see if the list is there?

@Petros I saw there and the ul tag is empty. I added a photo to you see in the post

@olamundo97 shouldn't there be two console logs? one from getMovie function and the other from useEffect?

@shindeshubhamm yeahh, you are right. It is not being console.log on the console. Maybe this is a tip of what the problem can be...

@olamundo97 the h3 element does not contain the word Movies. I know its a bit remote but any chance you are not rendering the correct component?

@olamundo97 the problem might be, effect ends before complete execution of fetchMovies. Since you have not awaited fetchMovies.

@shindeshubhamm this shouldn't be the case! No need to await for fetchMovies as the setState happens in it and nothing else after the invocation. Also we can see the console.log so...

@Petros, I realized if I reload the page, it is not calling the api anymore. Like, don't show in the console.log anymore. Maybe is it the problem?

Can we see the parent component? The one that renders Movies and passes in the prop mood?

@Petros, I will updated the post to show you. Basically, I am getting the mood from the user selection through the Onclick in the Main component

@olamundo97 Im confused! Was the Movies component an example to demonstrate an issue that you have? Or is it a real component in your codebase? Your Main component does not render the 'Movies` component.

@Petros Movies in my real componet. In the Main component there are options of mood to the system to choose a movie based on the mood of the person. So, Movie component is responsible to load the specifc movie based on the mood that the user selected in the Main component.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The problem was that the Movies component was used as a page rendered by the router. mood was a route parameter thus changed the code to:
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';


const Movies = () => {
    const { mood } = useParams();

    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchMovies = async () => {
            if (mood) {
                try {
                    const moviesData = await getMovie(mood);
                    console.log(moviesData);  // This logs the data correctly
                    setMovies(moviesData);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error("Error fetching movies:", error);
                }
            }
        };

        fetchMovies();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div style={{ padding: "128px" }}>
            <h3>Movies</h3>
            <ul>
                {movies.map((movie) => (
                    <li key={movie.id}>
                        <div>{movie.title}</div>
                        <div>{movie.genre}</div>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Movies;

